# return a sliced string to the orginal string

Tags: python, string

if I have two strings

```
s1='abcdefghi'

s2='jklmnopqr'
```

I slice the first string `s1` into sub-string `['abc','def','ghi']`,then I **encode** it with function which gives number for each sub-sequence `[10,2,33]`.
Then  I decode it with other function **decode** whitch return `['abc','def','ghi']`.

The same thing for string `s2`

Now, I want to know after decoding how to return the sub-strings`['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr']` into the 
original strings `s1='abcdefghi'`and `s2='jklmnopqr'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

For your updated question, you can use this:

```
>>> lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']
>>> s1, s2 = map("".join, zip(lst[::3], lst[1::3], lst[2::3]))
>>> s1
'abcdefghi'
>>> s2
'jklmnopqr'
>>>
```

In the above demonstration, `lst` represents the list returned by your function.

Answer (score 2):

String in Python are immutable. It means that you cannot change string objects. If you re-use identifier in assignment, you create a new string object

```
>>> s = 'a'
>>> id(s)
10767896
>>> s = 'b'
>>> id(s)
10767920
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join()`:

```
data = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
s = ''.join(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> decodes = ['abc','def','ghi']
>>> ''.join(decodes)
'abcdefghi'
>>> answer = ''.join(decodes)
>>> print(answer)
abcdefghi
```